# Get the Fail2Ban jail which banned an IP address

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

There are a lot of reasons why someone want to know the jail that banned an IP address, but I do not find a `fail2ban-client` command to tell me this. There should be a `get` command that doesn't require `<JAIL>`, but instead outputs it.

I am aware that starting with version v0.10.2 I can unban an IP with:

```
fail2ban-client unban 192.0.2.138
```

My Question is not how to unban the IP. I ask how can I find out the jail that banned the IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer versions (0.10.6/0.11.2) of fail2ban can handle this using `fail2ban-client banned <IP>`, see [RFE 2725](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2725#issuecomment-631519265).
This would return list of jails where given IP is currently banned.

Comment: Hm. I guess that the Ubuntu maintainers ought to keep `fail2ban` up to date, then. It's mid-January 2021 and Ubuntu 20.04.1 is stuck with 0.11.1. Oh well.

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn: 20.04 is a *long-term support* version. It's normal that it doesn't always have the newest features, as it focuses on stability.

Comment: @EsaJokinen — aye, you're quite right. I actually asked for an update from the package manager; he suggested that I'd do my own backport and put it on a PPA  I'll think about it...

Comment: Good news, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS already has updated `fail2ban` to version 0.11.2, and the command above certainly works!

Answer (score 7):

The `fail2ban-client status JAIL` command shows a list of IP addresses *currently* banned by that jail, but it's a bit laborous to go through every jail like that, and it also won't show you IP addresses that are already released from the jail.

The best way to gather the knowledge you need is to search for the IP address from the Fail2Ban logs:

```
# grep "192.0.2.138" /var/log/fail2ban.log
fail2ban.actions  [388]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 192.0.2.138
fail2ban.actions  [388]: NOTICE  [sshd] Unban 192.0.2.138
fail2ban.filter   [388]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.0.2.138 - 2020-12-24 10:52:42
fail2ban.filter   [388]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.0.2.138 - 2020-12-24 10:52:43
fail2ban.filter   [388]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.0.2.138 - 2020-12-24 10:52:47
fail2ban.filter   [388]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.0.2.138 - 2020-12-24 10:52:51
fail2ban.filter   [388]: INFO    [sshd] Found 192.0.2.138 - 2020-12-24 10:52:56
fail2ban.actions  [388]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 192.0.2.138
```

This will not only show which jail banned the IP but also *why* – with all the timestamps you can use to find the corresponding events from the logs Fail2Ban is monitoring.

Comment: Because it had some typos, formatting and language problems. It's a normal practice here to fix those kind of things.

Comment: Take also in account that machines, not only humans, are reading ServerFault. They have a far more limited ability to deal with typos and bad grammar than humans. For example, writing _baned_ instead of _banned_ means that search engines might not be able to tag this question correctly, and that means that fewer people will find it. It also means that automatic translation will fail — it's hard enough to translate _correct_ spelling & grammar. These are _also_ perfectly valid reasons for doing some spelling corrections here and there.

Comment: @MaxMuster - anyone with enough points can edit anyone's question and answer. When you have enough points, you can reject someone's edit. Some have enough points to close and delete your question.

Comment: @MaxMuster I'm not sure if you ever published anything through a respectable publisher, but for the sake of the argument, I'll assume you have. When the publisher accepts your manuscript, or draft publication, an editor will go through it, word by word. And they will flag common mistakes, grammar errors, poor style, or ask for clarification when a sentence is obscure. That's the editor's prerrogative; by accepting to submit a publication through _their_ service, you abide by whatever silly rules the editor imposes, in order to get published. If you disagree, you go to a different one, right?

Comment: @MaxMuster StackExchange does not have _one_ editor, but the principle is the same. By participating in this community, you accept its own rules, guidelines, principles, and so forth. Editing a question for clarity is, indeed, common procedure — because it will be helpful to anyone else with the same question. You are _not_ 'forced' to accept SO's rules and guidelines. You are _always_ entitled to ask your question on any other help community out there — that's your prerrogative and privilege. However, if you want to do it _here_, you have to accept those rules, even if you don't like them.

Comment: @MaxMuster Even better... when publishing under a respectable publisher, you have *no choice* but to accept their rules, or try a different one. SO is different: you can actually participate on Meta, propose a rule change, and get the community vote on those changes. You have actually a good chance of getting your proposal approved if you have good arguments for changing rules. If your proposal is _not_ accepted, the good news is that you can reformulate it, submit it again for discussion, and possibly get a new vote on the changes. All of that is possible in SO!

Comment: @MaxMuster On the other hand, all that the community 'demands' in return is that, _until_ you get the rules changed by all, you respect the rules 'as is'. That's not much to ask, is it? It's also, uh, interpersonal respect towards those who have been volunteering their efforts so far to get the community rules applied so that SO is useful for the largest number of people possible. And that's the kind of respect you also wish those very same volunteers to have once you get _your_ rules approved — you wish to continue to count on them to apply your rules as well as they did the others, right?

Comment: @MaxMuster Last but not least, these comments are _so_ far from the topic, the question, or even outside the scope of SO itself, that I'd flag myself for review  It _is_ very likely that a moderator _will_ consider that my above comments are not appropriate at all for this question and delete them without even notifying me. Possibly even suspending my account, or removing karma points, or something. I'll learn my lesson and stick to giving answers instead of lectures!

Comment: That said, I'd just comment that the above solution is possibly the only _easy_ and _straightforward_ solution for pre-0.11.2 versions of `fail2ban-client`, while not necessarily being the 'best'. Fortunately, it seems that 0.11.2 is becoming the standard in most distros in 2022...